# Grouping file names in clusters

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I am using this line to read all Images in a file:

```
imagefiles = dir('Images\*.jpg');
```

Suppose I have the names: `a1.jpg`,`a11.jpg`,`b13.JPG`,`b5.JPG`,`c1.jpg`.

How do I group together all images with no more than 2 different characters (the number) in their name. for the given example group together all `a` and all `b` and atheired group for `c`.

By grouping I mean form some kind of data structure or order that will enable me to access each group separately for later processing?

I am assuming the file type is always 'jpg' and the numbers will always be smaller then 100 and positive. I am assuming a not case sensitive code regarding file type, that is `jpg` and `JPG` may appear (I don't know regular expression but will be happy to learn from a good link as well)

Comment: I don't understand what your grouping criteria means.

Comment: What would be your expected grouping output?

Comment: I tried to edit it to a clearer version. Is it good enough?

Comment: So you want to group based in the first character of the name? So a1, a45, a98 will go to one group, b2, b14, b45 to the second group... Is it always only the first character used to group? Or you can have more than one character? Ex: ac12, ac15, ac47 to the same group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could capture the initial non-number part of the file name using `regexp`, group them with `unique` and put them in a struct.

```
% Some test data
files = {'a11','a1','b2','a32','ca3','b45','c1','ca2'};
files = strcat(files, '.jpg');

% Capture and group
tag = regexp(files,'^\D+','match','once');
[unTag, ~, unIdx] = unique(tag);
for idx = 1:length(unTag)
    fileGroups.(unTag{idx}) = files(unIdx == idx);
end

% The result
>> fileGroups = 
     a: {'a11.jpg'  'a1.jpg'  'a32.jpg'}
     b: {'b2.jpg'  'b45.jpg'}
     c: {'c1.jpg'}
    ca: {'ca3.jpg'  'ca2.jpg'}
```

Depending on how your filenames you might have to update to a more detailed regular expression. You could use `\D+(?=\d+\.(JPG|jpg))` to caputure a non-digit char before some number and the .jpg extension.

So if your file names are something like:

```
>> files
    'dummyStr_a11.jpg'
    'dummyStr_a1.jpg'
    'dummyStr_b2.jpg'
    'dummyStr_a32.jpg'
    'dummyStr_ca3.jpg'
    'dummyStr_b45.jpg'
    'dummyStr_c1.jpg'
    'dummyStr_ca2.jpg'
```

Capture with something like

```
tag = regexp(files,'[a-z]+(?=\d+\.(JPG|jpg))','match','once');
>> tag = 
'a'    'a'    'b'    'a'    'ca'    'b'    'c'    'ca'
```

Comment: Very Informative. Thanks a lot.  what does the `~` in `[unTag, ~, unIdx]` means? that you do not save that data?

Comment: @havakok Yes, the ~ tells Matlab to ignore that output. This was [introduced from R2009b](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/). Read more about it [here](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-outputs.html).